# converting str to int

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a text file and trying to process it. at the end I have to convert one of the variables from `str` to `int`.
if I print the variable using this command:

```
print(y_test.iloc[:,1])
```

I would get the following results:

```
0     B
1     B
2     A
3     A
4     A
5     A
6     A
7     A
8     B
9     B
10    B
11    B
12    B
13    B
Name: group, dtype: object
```

and if I get the type of this variable:

```
print(type(y_test.iloc[:,1]))
```

I would get this output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

but my expected output is this (A to 0 and B to 1):

```
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    0
```

to do so, I tried the following code:

```
y2 = int(y_test.iloc[:,1])
```

but did not return what I want. do you know how to do that?

Comment: can you please share the text file?

Comment: *"did not return what I want"* Can you expand?

Comment: @PeterWood: in fact gives error.

Comment: "my expected output is this (A to 0 and B to 1)" - Python cannot read your mind. There needs to be some logic somewhere that specifies this translation rule. Just `int` tries to treat text as if it represented numbers in base 10 digits.

Comment: @user7249622 I was prompting you to tell us what the error is and to improve the question. Not in the comments, edit and improve the question. See [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

To get A as 1 and B (or anything else) as 0 you can use the below. It converts all A's to True, which are then converted to the integer value of True, which is 1.

`(y_test.iloc[:,1] == 'A').astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `replace()`:

```
y_test.iloc[:, 1].replace({'B': 0, 'A': 1})
```